# Copy Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to copy an installed Visual Studio 2010 to another without redownloading again? I lost my installers so I'm looking if it can be done thru copying the folders and running the installer and stuff..

Comment: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/3873-backup-and-transfer-program-from-one-computer-to-another May be this link would work for you

Comment: Thanks. It looks promising, so I'll give it a try.